# Double cover - smoothness of branch curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex projective surfaces, where $Y$ is smooth. Suppose $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is finite degree two map, i.e. $X$ is a double cover of $Y$. Let $B\subset  Y$ denote the branch curve. It is known that if $B$ is smooth, then $X$ is smooth. And in general, $X$ can have singularities at most over the singular points of $B$.

In case of double covers, is the converse true? That is, if $X$ is smooth, then does it imply that $B$ is smooth?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\tau \colon X \to X$ be the involution of the double cover. If $X$ is smooth then the fixed locus $R \subset X$ of $\tau$ (i.e., ramification divisor of $p$) is also smooth. The map $p$ induces an isomorphism $R \to B$, hence $B$ is also smooth.

Comment: can you tell me why $R$ will be smooth?

Comment: The fixed locus of a finite group action on a smooth variety (over a field of characteristic coprime to the order of the group) is always smooth, because the tangent sheaf to the fixed locus, being the group invariants in the restriction of the ambient tangent bundle, is its direct summand, hence locally free.